# Count outlets that have transactions for 3 consecutive months, respectively

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to count how many outlet thas have a transactions for 3 consecutive months.

| month | outletid |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01 | A |
| 2023-02 | A |
| 2023-03 | A |
| 2023-03 | B |
| 2023-04 | B |
| 2023-05 | A |
| 2023-05 | B |

the expected result:

| month | counter |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01 | - |
| 2023-02 | - |
| 2023-03 | 1 |
| 2023-04 | 0 |
| 2023-05 | 1 |

In 2023-03, there are 1 outlet because outletid A has a transaction in 2023-01, 2023-02, and 2023-03
In 2023-05, there are 1 outlet because outletid B has a transaction in 2023-03, 2023-04, and 2023-05

this is my query

```
SELECT 
  month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT outletid) AS 3_consecutive_month
FROM(
  SELECT 
    month,
    outletid,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY outletid ORDER BY month ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS count_month
  FROM transaction_data
)
WHERE count_month=3
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month
```

Comment: Hi - so what have you tried and what issues are you facing? You need to show at least some attempt at solving this yourself

Comment: Also, are you actually holding the month values as shown (I.e. as strings) or are they actually dates that you’ve formatted just to show the year-month? If these aren’t dates it will significantly increase the challenge

Comment: the result is 1 in 2023-03 (true), - in 2023-04 (somehow true), and 2 in 2023-05 (wrong) 


SELECT 
  month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT outletid) AS 3_consecutive_outlet
FROM(
  SELECT 
    month,
    outletid,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY outletid ORDER BY month ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS count_month
  FROM transaction_data

Comment: @NickW i just added the query